# Using Binomial distribution to evaluate sums

Tags: calculus, probability

We know if $X$ is binomial random variable with parameter $n,p$, the mass function is given by $p_X(i) = {n \choose i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} $ and $\sum_{i=0}^n p_X(i) = 1 $.

If we put $p=1/2$, we see that $\sum {n \choose i} = 2^n $. Is this a valid reasoning? or is it circular reasoning?

In general, one can write

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} \left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^i = \frac{1}{(1-p)^n} $$

where $0 \leq p \leq 1$

For instance, one can put $p = \sin^2 \alpha $ and we obtain an identity

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n  {n \choose i} \tan^{2i} \alpha = \frac{1}{\cos^{2n} \alpha} $$

which is probably useless, but anyway, my question is, can we use the distribution as such or we are just in a circular reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All comes down to the equality:$$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}ix^iy^{n-i}=(x+y)^n\tag1$$where $n$ is a nonnegative integer and $x,y$ are real (or complex if you like) numbers.

It can be shown that this is true if $x,y\geq0$ with $x+y=1$ (corresponding with binomial distribution) purely on base of probability theory.

Then on base of that result it is also possible to deduce the more general case $(1)$.

So the reasoning you mention is valid.

I would not advice though to involve binomial distribution to evaluate sums.

Why should we if we have $(1)$ on our plate already?